# app script receiving variable into library

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a bound script for a sheet that also uses a standalone script in library resources. I am trying to send the sheet ID to the library so that the standalone script can use that ID.

Bound Script to send ID to function copyLastRow

```
function onOpen() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Get Active spreadsheet object
var sh = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet(); // Get Active sheet's object
var shId = sh.getSheetId();
Invoice.copyLastRow(shId);
}
```

The problem I have is not know the correct code to retreive the ID in the standalone script (Invoice). Please can anyone give example.

Comment: How is it that you have a standalone script in a library.  A standalone script by definition has no container.  So how is a standalone script contained within a library?

Comment: The standalone script can access any spreadsheet or file on it's own.  Just put the id somewhere and let the Standalone Script go get it.

Comment: Oh btw simple trigger cannot perform any actions that require permission.

Comment: standalone script Project key added to library resource in bound script. I have multiple sheets that need to send their ID to standalone. If I needed to update part of script I only have standalone to change if that makes sense. So when trigger on form update in each sheet takes place it sends ID. just not sure what to place on standalone and how to use get that ID.

Comment: Is Invoice that name of a library? If it is then were probably not talking about a standalone script as defined [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) were just talking about a library.  And I think you're problem is just the simple trigger.

Comment: simple triggers cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the Language service, which is anonymous.

Comment: [simple trigger restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onMyOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Get Active spreadsheet object
  var sh = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet(); // Get Active sheet's object
  var shId = sh.getSheetId();
  Invoice.copyLastRow(shId);
}
```

Run this first:

```
function createTriggerforAboveFunction() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if(!isTrigger(onMyOpen())) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onMyOpen').forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onOpen().create();
  }
}
```

helper function:

```
function isTrigger(funcName){
  var r=false;
  if(funcName){
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for (let i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
      if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
        r=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

[simple trigger restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)